# Lightgbm can't access data from Dataset get_field method

Tags: python, lightgbm

I have got a simple lgbm dataset:

```
import lightgbm as lgbm

dataset = lgbm.Dataset(data=X, label=y, feature_name=X.columns.tolist())
```

Where **X** is a pandas df, and **y** a pandas series. I want to access a specific column of **X** in my custom objective function. But when I try:

```
data = dataset.get_field('data')
```

I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-71-34d27860b9e3>", line 1, in <module>
    data = dataset.get_field('data')

  File "/Users/***/anaconda3/envs/py3k/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py", line 1007, in get_field
    ctypes.byref(out_type)))

  File "/Users/***/anaconda3/envs/py3k/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lightgbm/basic.py", line 48, in _safe_call
    raise LightGBMError(_LIB.LGBM_GetLastError())

LightGBMError: b'Field not found'
```

Whereas this works well:

```
y = dataset.get_field('label')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible.

The `data` seems to be the core of a dataset, whereas the rest of `lgb.Dataset` constructor arguments are handled as additional features. You can see all of them other than the data end up in `lgb.Dataset.set_field` function as can be tracked in the `_lazy_init` [function](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/v2.1.1/python-package/lightgbm/basic.py#L638). Filed setting in C back-end is handled by `SetXXXField`  functions as handled by the [LGBM_DatasetSetField function](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/v2.1.1/src/c_api.cpp#L745). You will see that those calls do not appear elsewhere in `c_api.cpp`